# import of a opj file (Origin)

Tags: import

Is there a way to import a file of opj-type? Or do you know a package to convert the data? The `Import[]` function seems not to know this format.

Comment: I don't know, but I wouldn't have high hopes for it. Origin's file format seems not to be publicly documented, and there are many different and incompatible versions of it.

Comment: unfortunately, even opj2dat failed to convert the file, although it's only a tiny 2D list

Comment: This project: [liborigin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/liborigin/) (GPL license) provides a C library that might be useful.

Comment: OriginLab provides a tool, [Mathematica Link](http://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/ExternalAPP-Mathematica-Link), that apparently works with older versions of *Mathematica* (4.2 through 7) but is not compatible with *Mathematica* 8 or higher.